# Why Windows 8 is giving low battery warning sometimes at 7%, sometimes at 10%?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery

My Windows 8.0 behaves inconsistently with low battery warnings. Sometimes I receive it at 7% of battery, sometimes at 10%.

I thought it depends of current power plan, but settings of ALL plans are the same:

```
                           On battery     Plugged in
----------------------------------------------------------
Low battery level              10%           10%
Critical battery level          5%            5%
Reserve battery level           0%            7%
```

Do you know any reason why Windows is throwing low battery warning at 7%? Obviously, preset value is always 10%, why is warning at 10% skipped? (And from where comes that 7% warning level?)

**Edit:** image attached:

[image]

Comment: Are the low battery and reserve battery level warnings even different?  Whats more likely is your battery is discharging from say 11% to 7%.  Are you using the OEM software to manage the charge or just windows?

Comment: Is your battery getting old?  Its possible that it's getting unstable as it ages and dropping quickly from 10-7%.

Comment: @Ramhound – I have added a screenshot, levels are managed by Windows. Tab *Lenovo Energy Management* contains only button leading to [this screen](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3464/2336) so I don't think OEM software is managing battery levels. (Or might be there a side effect? :)

Comment: @uSlackr – good question. I'm experiencing this since first days of my laptop. Current wear state of the battery (after 1.5 years) is 11% (according to [Battery Bar Pro](http://batterybarpro.com/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found potential reason.

10% level is always in effect and usually works.

**BUT** I observed that battery sometimes fails to report its charge level continuously, regardless of used monitoring software. During decrease of charge, it gets stuck at **14%**, then indicating **no changes for a few minutes** and then suddenly showing **7%**.
During this sudden change from 14% to 7%, battery alarm for 10% level goes off, but displaying current level what is 7%. **So I can actually see alarm triggered by 10% level but showing 7%.**

Comment: perhaps there are driver or system software updates available.